# Xamarin.iOS / SfDataGrid on iPhone 10 is crashing

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I have been using SfDataGrid in a deployed application for over a year without any issues. Recently the iPhone 10 was released and I noticed that the datagrid is crashing, but only on iPhone 10. Previous phones work without any issues.

Below is the error and stack trace from the crash and it is coming from within the SfDataGrid component:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.VisualContainer.set_VerticalOffset (System.Double value) [0x00006] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.VisualContainer.VisualContainer_Scrolled (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0001c] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
at UIKit.UIScrollView+_UIScrollViewDelegate.Scrolled (UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIScrollView.g.cs:1364 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIView.AddSubview (UIKit.UIView view) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIView.g.cs:270 
at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.gridLoaded () [0x0001c] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.LayoutSubviews () [0x00008] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
at AppName.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in AppName.iOS/Main.cs:12
```

Does anyone know if there's a fix for this?

I did notice that a basic configuration of the SfDataGrid does work ok even on iPhone 10, but when I start using more custom configuration options in the grid it starts to crash. I have not been able to pin point which specific configuration is causing this just yet.

Any help / info would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to debug to find out which line caused the error.

Comment: @ColeXia thanks, not very helpful, I'm obviously already debugging this. 
Syncfusion SfDataGrid component crashes with an error internal to it that I have no access to. The crash happens somewhere in the lifecycle of the component. The line that causes this error is basically the presenting of the viewcontroller that hosts this grid component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have fixed the reported crashing of SfDataGrid in iPhone 10. This issue has been included in our upcoming releases, which is scheduled to be rolled out by the End of December 2017. If the custom assemblies are required, please contact us through the direct trac incident.

Direct trac link: https://www.syncfusion.com/account/login

Regards,

Shivagurunathan. K

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using SfDataGrid control.

We have tested our SfDataGrid in Xamarin.iOS platform with IPhone X emulator and we are able to reproduce the reported application crash. We confirmed that the reported issue is a defect. This fix will be included in the upcoming 2017 Volume 4 SP1 release which will be roll out End of December, 2017.

Regards,

Ashok

Answer (score 1):

We are glad to announce that our Essential Studio Volume 4, Service Pack 1, 2017 (Version 15.4.0.20) is rolled out with fix for Application crashed while run in IPhone X issue and is available for download under the following link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/135223/essential-studio-2017-volume-4-service-pack-release-v15-4-0-20-available-for-download

Regards,

Ashok